# google maps v3 put drawing and mapTypeControls in my custom control

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have created a div that shows various information and options about my map. I am adding this control to the map with

"map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(document.getElementById('accordionContainer')"

I would like to put the default mapTypeControls in this control, but I don't see any way to move the mapTypeControl to another control.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Error:-

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ",", void expected after 
     this token
    - InformationCapture cannot be resolved to a 
     type

Error line in my console:-   Intent ob = new Intent(NearestStore.this,InformationCapture.class);
```

Code:-

C